# Can I connect a SATA-II hard drive to a SATA-I connection?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have an older computer with a SATA-I connection.  My hard drive crashed and I need to buy a new hard drive.  Will I run into problems if I connect a SATA-II drive to my computer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, SATA-II is backwards-compatible. You'll only be able to use SATA-I bandwidth (150 MB/s), but since that is well above what normal hard drives deliver, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: that's what i thought too, but i've got recent Seagate SATA-II drives that aren't playing nice with my onboard SATA-I controller.  no jumpers to force it either.  could be a bios config issue, i gave up and put them on an internal sataII controller.

Comment: I finally got everything connected up about a week ago and it worked like a champ, no problems.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the "(150 MB/s) is well above what normal hard drives deliver", actually. I just checked the throughput on my most recent ZFS scrub (which is pretty a random-I/O intensive operation) on the large single-disk spinning-platter pool, and that shows ~124 MB/s in verification data throughput. (1.47TB verified as correct on disk in 3 hours 27 minutes.) If that disk was using SATA-I, that wouldn't leave much margin for lower-level stuff, let alone that ZFS scrubbing is an *online* operation. *This doesn't invalidate the answer, though.*