# GX280 SATA or SATA-III

Tags: hard-drive, sata, dell-optiplex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I connect a SATA-II hard drive to a SATA-I connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/52001/can-i-connect-a-sata-ii-hard-drive-to-a-sata-i-connection)

I have a GX280, and want to upgrade the harddrive.  Can I use SATA-II and/or SATA-III harddrives with this computer?  I understand that I will not get the full speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are indeed backwards compatible. It would be an anomaly if they were not. Some drives are set with a jumper.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA#Backward_and_forward_compatibility

Practical discussion with guys who have done it:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/243507-32-sata-compatible-sata-ports (read all the way down though)